# change UISwitch default color for OFF state and border colors

Tags: ios, uiswitch, tintcolor

I have take a reference of following [How to change UISwitch default color for OFF state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616900/how-to-change-uiswitch-default-color-for-off-state)

**I have got following code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
      
    self.termSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;  
    [self SwitchStatus];

    
   }


- (IBAction)SwitchStatusChange:(id)sender {
     [self SwitchStatus];
}
- (void)SwitchStatus {
    if ( self.termSwitch.on) {
         [ self.termSwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
         [ self.termSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [ self.termSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        
    }else{
         [ self.termSwitch setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        
        [ self.termSwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        
        [ self.termSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.384f green:0.859f blue:0.427f alpha:1.00f]];
    }

}
```

**I am unable to place the white border for the switch and switch is not smooth as default**

[image]

I have checked the below link but it doesn't work for me

[How to set UISwitch border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959403/how-to-set-uiswitch-border-color)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. You are not doing anything that would change the border color, so naturally the border color does not change. If you want a different border color, *set* the border color:

```
// s is a UISwitch
s.layer.borderWidth = 1
s.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
s.layer.cornerRadius = 16
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works out . Do you have any idea how can i make it smooth

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "smooth". I tried this and the UISwitch works _exactly_ like an unmodified UISwitch. I am not doing anything that would affect the "smoothness" of the switch.

Comment: after using it animation of ON/OFF is lost .it moves fast when ON/OFF is done  and doesn't behave as original

Comment: That is not true. I have added a screencast showing that animation is smooth. Maybe _you_ are doing something that wrecks the animation, but _I_ am not.

Comment: My code is exactly what I showed you. - Your problem is probably that you are _changing_ the switch exactly at the time that _it is trying to animate_. _You_ are messing up the animation with what you are doing in your `SwitchStatus` method. But that is not _my_ fault. I answered the question you asked: how to show the border. If you now have a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: If u gt any ideas what i have messed up in SwitchStatus function then i would feel grateful if u notify me ab that

Comment: I have accepted your answer for ur help and  for the correct answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481559/swrevealviewcontroller-make-sidebar-button-static-make-the-rearview-appear-on-to Any ideas ab this question